# No antialiasing for iOS 8 safari webgl

Tags: webgl, mobile-safari

Safari on iOS 8 supporting webgl is surely a good news but after I run my demo I find that there is no antialiasing. Any solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

role you own? There's lots of ways to anti-alias. Here's one. First check that you're not already anti-aliased

```
var gl = someCanvas.getContext("webgl");
var contextAttribs = gl.getContextAttributes();
if (!contextAttribs.antialias) {
  // do your own anti-aliasing
}
```

The simplest way would be to make your canvas's backing store larger than it's displayed. Assuming you have a canvas that you want to be displayed a certain size

```
canvas.width = desiredWidth * 2;
canvas.height = desiredHeight * 2;
canvas.style.width = desiredWidth + "px";
canvas.style.height = desiredHeight + "px";
```

Now your canvas will most likely be bi-linear filtered when drawn. In iOS's case since they are all HD-DPI you probably will need to do 4x

```
canvas.width  = desiredWidth  * 4;
canvas.height = desiredHeight * 4;
canvas.style.width  = desiredWidth  + "px";
canvas.style.height = desiredHeight + "px";
```

You can find out by looking at `window.devicePixelRatio`. In fact if you want 1x1 pixels you'd do this

```
var devicePixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
var overdraw = 1; // or 2
var scale = devicePixelRatio * overdraw;
canvas.width  = desiredWidth  * scale;
canvas.height = desiredHeight * scale;
canvas.style.width  = desiredWidth  + "px";
canvas.style.height = desiredHeight + "px";
```

Otherwise, another way is to render to a texture attached to a framebuffer then render the texture into the canvas [using a shader that does antialiasing](http://www.glge.org/demos/fxaa/).

Comment: The problem is resolved by enlarging the canvas. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, gman. I know that you are an expert in WebGL. I encountered another problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530799/projective-texture-mapping-in-webgl I'm waiting for your answer.