# Why does this algorithmic shader have bad aliasing

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, glsl, webgl, shader

When I use this shader I get a really badly aliased edge

```
#define angle (10.0*3.1415/180.0)
void main(void)
{
    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
    if(((150.0)+angle*gl_FragCoord.x) > gl_FragCoord.y) {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0,255,0,1.0);
    } else {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0,0,0,1.0);
    }
}
```

You can see what I am refering to at this shadertoy:
https://www.shadertoy.com/view/lsjXRR

is there a way to reduce the aliasing between the two colors (or textures if I was to use them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While turning anti-aliasing/multisampling on helps greatly (as @gman) correctly points out, you can also change your fragment function to slightly smooth out the boundary between black and green.

**Edit** in response to comment.

Instead of doing a hard branch, try to derive an interpolation factor around the boundary of your condition:

```
#define angle (10.0*3.1415/180.0)
void main(void)
{
  vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
  float f = (((150.0)+angle*gl_FragCoord.x) - gl_FragCoord.y) * 0.003;
  float f2 = clamp(f, -0.5, 0.5) + 0.5;
  gl_FragColor = mix(vec4(0,255,0,1.0), vec4(0,0,0,1.0), f2);
}
```

(This moves the line, but gives an idea of how to do it). If you paste it into shadertoy, it gives you a perfectly anti-aliased (but slightly blurry) line.

Comment: Multisampling isn't helping in my actual webGL project (the shadertoy example is a really basic version of the same issue)

I'm finding that the blending needs to be in the shader as you say. Is there a 1 pass approach of doing this that you know of?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what answer you're looking for but I'd guess it's because anti-aliasing is off on ShaderToy.

1. Went to your link (https://www.shadertoy.com/view/lsjXRR)
2. Opened a javascript console
3. typed

   ```
   context.rawgl.getContextAttributes()
   ```

   which printed

   ```
   WebGLContextAttributes {
       failIfMajorPerformanceCaveat: false, 
       preserveDrawingBuffer: false,   
       premultipliedAlpha: false, 
       antialias: false,                      // <==--    
       stencil: true…,
   }
   ```

## Update

So apparently MSAA anti-aliasing only happens on the edges of the primitives being drawn. Since you're drawing a single quad and your "edge" is not from the edge of a primitive but instead is computed in your fragment shader MSAA anti-aliasing has no effect.

[This article explains it in more detail](http://mynameismjp.wordpress.com/2012/10/24/msaa-overview/)

If you want to anti-alias for your case either smooth out your function like @Alexander suggests, [step up your canvas resolution, or apply a post processing anti-aliasing algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25397764/128511).

Comment: sadly multisampling doesn't help when the aliasing is in the shader itself. this image shows that sampling is enabled on the quad I'm rendering, but not on the shader http://i.imgur.com/6ifbem9.png