# Projective texture mapping in WebGL

Tags: webgl, texture-mapping

I wrote two simple WebGL demos which use a 512x512 image as texture. But the result is not what I want. I know the solution is to use projective texture mapping(or any other solutions?) but I have no idea how to implement it in my simple demos. Anyone can help?

The results are as follows(both of them are incorrect):

[image]

[image]

Codes of demos are here: https://github.com/jiazheng/WebGL-Learning/tree/master/texture

[image]

note: Both the model and texture could not be modified in my case.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get perspective-correct texture mapping, you must actually be using perspective. That is, instead of narrowing the top of your polygon along the *x* axis, move it backwards along the *z* axis, and apply a standard perspective projection matrix.

I'm a little hazy on the details myself, but my understanding is that the way the perspective matrix maps the *z* coordinate into **the *w* coordinate** is the key to getting the GPU to interpolate along the surface “correctly”.

If you have already-perspective-warped 2D geometry, then you will have to implement some method of restoring it to 3D data, computing appropriate *z* values. There is no way in WebGL to get a perspective quadrilateral, because the primitives are *triangles* and there is not enough information in three points to define the texture mapping you're looking for unambiguously — your code must use the four points to work out the corresponding depths. Unfortunately, I don't have enough grasp of the math to advise you on the details.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. In my situation the model and the texture cannot be edited.

Comment: @jz1108 That's key information; please edit your question to include it. I've edited my answer to discuss that case.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify vec4 texture coordinates not vec2. The 4th field in each vec4 will be homogeneous w that when divided into x and y produce your desired coordinate. This in turn should allow the perspective correction division in hardware to give you a non affine mapping within the triangle provided your numbers are correct. Now, if you use a projection matrix to transform a vec4 with w=1 in your vertex shader you should get the correct vec4 numbers ready for perspective correction going into setup and rasterization for your fragment shader. If this is unclear then you need to seek out tutorials on projective texture transformation and homogeneous coordinates in projection.